# PHP PDO I can't login with a newly added credentials

Tags: php, pdo

Well after a lot of help trying to learn using classes/functions in php, I have come to another stump in my learning process :-)

I can register a user but every time I try to logon using those newly made creds, "Invalid credentials"

After echoing out some results, I find that it always sends back 0 records, I know my db connection is working because I use the same connection to register!

Any help, is as usual greatly appreciated!

hers is the code example of my connection and login function....

```
    <?php
class UsersLib
{   
    private $con;
    public function  __construct() {               
        $this->con = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$SQLServer;Database=$SQLDB", $SQLUser, $SQLPass);
    }


    public function Login($username, $password)
    {
        try {

                $query = $this->con->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE (username=:username OR email=:username) AND password=:password"); 
                $query->bindParam("username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $enc_password = hash('sha256', $password);
                $query->bindParam("password", $enc_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->execute();
                $Str =  "Rows  " .$query->rowCount(). " User Name  $username.";
                echo '<div style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:50px;">' .$Str. '</div>'; //Result of the row count and Post username
                if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
                    $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    return $result->user_id;                
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                exit($e->getMessage());
            }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The quotes are incorrect in the question. If this is the same in your real code you will get a fatal error. Please adjust.

Comment: You can't use the same named placeholder, unless emulation is on.

Comment: `$this->con = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=LocalHost;Database=DB, "User", "PassWord");`

Comment: Its always a good idea to check that the connection worked! [See example 1](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: @ RiggsFolly Sorry they are normally variables, that is a post typo, as i explained, I can register users using the same PDO connection, only when I try to read them back out does it read no records. this is my normal string... $this->con = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$SQLServer;Database=$SQLDB", $SQLUser, $SQLPass);

Comment: The syntax error is throwing off syntax highlighting.

Comment: I'll point back to my comment an hour ago and add a quote from the manual `You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.`

Answer (score 2):

You have double-quotes in the wrong place in your connection string.

Your SQL Server, PDO connection string should look like this:

`new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=DB", "User", "Password");`

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php

Comment: Sorry they are normally variables, that is a post typo, as i explained, I can register users using the same PDO connection, only when I try to read them back out does it read no records.                                                                     
 this is my normal string...                                                                                                 $this->con = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$SQLServer;Database=$SQLDB", $SQLUser, $SQLPass);

Comment: @Mark So why isn't that the code that we're all (still) seeing hasn't been shown in your question then?

Comment: Sorry, I have a lot of texts open at the same time and copied the wrong one, apologies! ;-)

Comment: Ooh I edited, now it looks like it should lol, I was wandering why the code was all red hehe ... What would help me a lot, is if i new how to echo the results from the $query any suggestions?

Comment: I can see you did a rowCount $Str, what's the value? Echo $result, and check its value too, then echo the exception to see what the likely error is. These may point to the areas area to check for your answer.

Comment: @OlusolaOmosola, I got 2 different results: 1. With the "where" clause I got '0', then if I remove the "where" and just do "Select * from users" I get '-1' I haven't had much luck with getting a $result, maybe it's the way I need to echo it out(My limitation because I am still trying to learn php :-) )

Comment: Can you check your table to be sure of your query? If you did Select *..., -1 is not the answer you should expect.

Comment: @OlusolaOmosola "select * from users;" (In the SQL server), shows me 1 rec, this is correct!